# Checking the response from an ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use the data sent back from my PHP file in an `if` statement.

I'm really not sure how to use AJAX, therefore after some research I have decided to ask here.

**Code**

```
function checkstatus(){
  $.post('wait.php',
  function(data){
    var status = data;
    if(status == "groda") {
      console.log("GRIS");
    } else {
      console.log("Sparris");
    }
  });
}
```

**Wait.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include('var.php');
include_once('dbi.php');
$email = $_SESSION["email"];
$gamecode = $_SESSION['gamekod'];
$id = $rid['id'];
$status;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $gamecode WHERE id='$id'";

if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      $gamestatus = $row['status'];
      mysqli_close($link);
    }
  }
}
?>
```

I have a PHP file (`wait.php`) which is getting a value from my database, then using the AJAX request I'm trying to see what the output from that file is. If the output is `groda` then it will log something and if it's not it won't.

My problem is that my if and else statement is not working. It updates from the database but the `==` part is not doing its job. Even if the value/data is `groda` it still logs `sparris`.

Comment: "How do i correctly write an if and else statement with data"...this is a bit vague. "Correctly" is by making it do whatever you want it to do based on the available data. You haven't given us a concrete problem to solve, but I'm going to guess your issue is that your `if` statement isn't doing what you expected, and that the cause of this may be because your PHP script isn't actually returning any data. But that's only a guess...can you confirm what your actual issue is (as opposed to positing a somewhat abstract question)?

Comment: My problem is that my if and else statement is not working. It updates from the database but the == doesn't check. Even if the value/data is groda it still logs sparris. Hope this helps

Comment: "Even if the value/data is groda it still logs sparris" That's impossible (see https://jsfiddle.net/wpvoq58g for proof). More likely is that the data isn't what you think it is. Check for things like whitespace or other unexpected characters, especially at the beginning or end of the string (see https://jsfiddle.net/wpvoq58g/1/ for an example of the effect of something like that). Unfortunately you haven't shown us how you output from the PHP, nor any sample data, so I can't help you with that very much, except to say that you need to do some debugging using your browser tools

Comment: you answered my question, thank you. Would you please "answer question" with "check the output" or something like that, there were an "endless" amount of backspaces after groda ^^

Comment: No problem. P.S. There's no reason to edit your question to point out that it's solved - people can see that due to the answer being "accepted"  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Even if the value/data is groda it still logs sparris"

That's logically impossible (see https://jsfiddle.net/wpvoq58g for proof). A computer cannot go against the instructions you have given it. It will always process the same input in the same way, according to the program rules.

If you consider this fact, then it becomes trivially obvious that the real issue must be that `data` doesn't contain what you think it does. Check for things like whitespace or other unexpected characters, especially at the beginning or end of the string (see https://jsfiddle.net/wpvoq58g/1 for an example of the effect of something like that).

Then consider either cleansing your source data, if that's appropriate, or adding some code which will trim whitespace or other potential extraneous characters from the output before testing its value.

A very simple example - this will trim the whitespace from either end of the data string before comparing it to the hard-coded value:

```
if(status.trim() == "groda") {
     console.log("GRIS");
} else {
     console.log("Sparris");
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/wpvoq58g/2/ for a demo.